# Issuer can not see the transaction using IssueTokensFlow - Corda

Tags: blockchain, corda

I want to issue tokens from a Party to an account in another Party.
The party that has the account is seing the transaction / state, but the issuer Party ins't. I need the issuer can see the transaction. I'm using IssueTokensFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I assume that you're using Tokens SDK.
- If you open the `FungibleToken` class, you'll see that it inherits from `AbstractToken`:
  https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/4bab8e8f20fddbdda6a135f7ed16184de5e1b24a/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/contracts/states/FungibleToken.kt#L42
- Inside `AbstractToken` you'll see that `participants` is set to `holder`; meaning only the `holder` will register in its vault the resulting `FungibleToken` when the transaction is finalized, and that's the behavior that you're experiencing:
  https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/4bab8e8f20fddbdda6a135f7ed16184de5e1b24a/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/contracts/states/AbstractToken.kt#L24
- I'm not sure why you want the `issuer` to register the issued token, remember that in Corda data is distributed on a need to know basis and not all nodes should see all data of the ledger, your `issuer` should issue the token and sort of "forget about it" (i.e only the `holder` is now aware of the token).
- Anyway, if you want the issuer to also register the resulting token in its vault; you can add it as an **observer** in that transaction (meaning it will register all the states that result from that transaction whether the `issuer` is a `participant` or not); you can see here that the `IssueTokensFlow` has a parameter `observerSessions`:
  https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/4bab8e8f20fddbdda6a135f7ed16184de5e1b24a/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/workflows/flows/issue/IssueTokensFlow.kt#L51
- So you can create a session for the `issuer` (i.e. `FlowSession issuerSession = initiateFlow(issuer)`) and pass it to `IssueTokensFlow`.